# How can I get part of the user input in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, java.util.scanner

I want to make a java program that will take part of the user input and will store it in order to use it later on.
My input looks something like this:

```
Mary market 8 theatre 80 end
John books 45 end
```

The first field signifies the person's name and then follows a sequence of expenses with the name of the reason they gave the money for. The word end signifies the end of input for each person.

My question is how can I separate the field of the peoples' names as well as their expenses so I can have an output of the average of the expenses for each one of them?

Comment: Read the whole string in a line. Tokenize it using [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) or `string.split(..)` and then iterate on the string tokens till you see "end" string

Comment: No. don't use StringTokenizer, it has been deprecated for years, for good reason. Use the split(Regex r) method from String instead.  myInput.split(" "); should do, this returns an array with all words (separated by space) from a String called myInput

Comment: `string.split(" ")` will work **as long as** the user enters the words in the order you tell him to, Else you will just have to make him enter them separately.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends, if you have a strict agreement that input data will always have the same format as in your example, then you can simply use the string `.split(" ")` and read all the numbers for each line.

**Example**:

```
// or any other input, eg: List, BufferedReader, etc
String[] lines = new String[] {
        "Mary market 8 theatre 80 end",
        "John books 45 end"
};
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] raw = line.split(" ");
    String name = raw[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < raw.length; i += 2) {
        if (raw[i].equals("end")) break;
        String expenseName = raw[i];
        int cost = Integer.parseInt(raw[i+1]); 
        ... 
    }
}
```

But if no, then, probably better to use `RegExp` and find all digits in each line.

**Example**:

```
// or any other input, eg: List, BufferedReader, etc
String[] lines = new String[] {
        "Mary market 8 theatre 80 end",
        "John books 45 end"
};

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
for (String line : lines) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while(m.find()) {
        int cost = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!! Could you please check out my lately edited post and tell me why am I getting error messages? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

**In Case** the user enters input as you instructed:
Using `split()` String method
Main class

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Get Input
    String input = s.nextLine();

    //Split using Whitespace Regex (Or any regex if you want)
    String[] InputArray = input.split(" ");

    //Object to get person info later
    PersonExpense person = new PersonExpense(InputArray[0]);

    //Loop throw the array to get data
    for (int i = 1; i < InputArray.length ; i = i+2) {
        if (InputArray[i].toLowerCase().equals("end"))
            break;
        else{
               person.addExpenses(new Pair<>(InputArray[i],Integer.valueOf(InputArray[i+1])));
        }
    }

}
}
```

PersonExpense Class

```
public class PersonExpense {

private String PersonName;

//ArrayList of pairs to save the name and cost of the expense
private ArrayList<Pair <String,Integer> > expenses = new ArrayList <Pair <String,Integer> > ();

public PersonExpense(String personName) {
    PersonName = personName;
}

public void addExpenses(Pair<String, Integer> expense) {
    this.expenses.add(expense);
}

public ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> getExpenses() {
    return expenses;
}

public void setExpenses(ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> expenses) {
    this.expenses = expenses;
}

public String getPersonName() {
    return PersonName;
}

public void setPersonName(String personName) {
    PersonName = personName;
}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering could you please check my edited post? thank you in advance!!